# Have any prominent physicists been 'scooped'?

Tags: soft-question

I'm really curious as to whether any prominent physicists have had a major breakthrough, only to have another scientist publish the achievement before they managed to, and whether the credit was given to the former or the latter?

I'm not sure if this is too subjective, but I checked the help center and it seems to be more on the constructive side.

Comment: I think this question would be a better fit for [hsm.se]

Comment: Furthermore, I think this question is much too broad.

Comment: This question (v1) appears to be off-topic.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "scooped". Priority disputes are common in physics. A famous example is whether Hilbert formulated general relativity before Einstein. There's even a wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_scientific_priority_disputes